# How to perform mathematical operation on integers/double extracted from input.nextInt() / input.nextDouble()?

Tags: java

I am asking the user to write 2 integers and I need to perform some mathematical operations with them. How can I do it?

In this case, for example, I am selecting the "add" operation, I am writing the integers 2 and 3, and I would like to have "5" as the result.

PS: I need to use the "Switch" method.

[Output terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2ypE.png)

Best regards.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.out.println("List of operations: add subtract multiply divide alphabetize");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       
        System.out.print("Enter an operation: ");
        String type_operation = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();

        if ((new String(type_operation).equals("add")) || 
            (new String(type_operation).equals("substract")) ||
            (new String(type_operation).equals("multiply")) ||
            (new String(type_operation).equals("divide")) ||
            (new String(type_operation).equals("alphabetize")))  {
               
                    
                switch (type_operation) {
                    case "add":
                        
                        System.out.print("Enter two integers: ");
                        int integers_1 = input.nextInt();
                        System.out.println(integers_1);
                                 
        
                    case "substract":
                        System.out.print("Enter two integers: ");
                        int integers_2 = input.nextInt();
                        break;

                    case "multiply":
                        System.out.print( "Enter two doubles: ");
                        double integers_3 = input.nextDouble();
                        
                        break;

                    case "divide":
                        System.out.print("Enter two doubles: ");
                        double integers_4 = input.nextDouble();
                        break;

                    case "alphabetize":
                        System.out.print("Enter two Strings: ");
                        String integers_5 = input.nextLine();
                        break;
        }    
    
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid value.");
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I've removed the JavaScript tag.  This is not JavaScript.

Comment: Also, you probably want to declare all those variables much earlier in your program, otherwise they go out of scope before you can use them, which means their values will disappear.

Comment: It doesn’t really matter where they came from originally. Once you have two `int` variables `x` and `y`, you add them together with `x + y`

Comment: Thank you @TimMoore... the problem is that I am asking for both integers here: int integers_1 = input.nextInt();... unfortunately that is the format I need to follow... .... I cannot access to the second int.

Comment: To read two integes you need to call `nextInt()` twice. There is no other reasonable way. Its easiest to have two lines like `int integers_1 = input.nextInt();` only with two different variable names. Then print the sum (in the `"add"` case) with something like `System.out.println(integers_1 + integers_2);`. That’s all there is to it.